# Rotated pictures

Tags: mencoder

I'm a newbie to video encoding.
My problem is:
I have a set of pictures, some of them were taken with my camera rotated 90 degrees. I tried to use mencoder to make a movie with them but the result shows me the pictures made with the camera rotated appear unrotated.
How do I make a movie that respects the original pictures orientation?
I have a mix of rotated pictures and unrotated ones.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are these pictures in jpeg files, or some other file format?

Comment: All of them are *.JPG

Answer (score 0):

I made a script some years ago for this purpose. I call it **autorot**, but you can use any name for it. You should modify the variables

```
dimkonica=2112x2816
dimcanon=3264x2448
```

to values that match the sizes of your pictures. Here is the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
 echo "Usage: $0 <jpeg-file> [lossy]"
 echo "Auto-rotate *lossless* with jhead,"
 echo "or optionally, if bad image dimensions,"
 echo "auto-orient *lossy* with convert"
 exit
fi
name="$1"
name=${name%.*}
#echo $1
#echo $name
if [ "$1" == "$name".jpg ] || [ "$1" == "$name".JPG ] || [ "$1" == "$name".jpeg ] || [ "$1" == "$name".JPEG ]
then
 echo hej>/dev/null
else
 echo "Bad! $1 not a jpeg-file"
 exit
fi

dimkonica=2112x2816
dimcanon=3264x2448

dim=$(identify -ping "$1"|sed -e s/.*JPEG\ // -e s/\ .*//)
gw0=$(echo "$dim"|sed s/x.*//)
gw1=$((gw0/16*16))
gh0=$(echo "$dim"|sed s/.*x//)
gh1=$((gh0/16*16))

if [ "$dim" == "$dimkonica" ] || [ "$dim" == "$dimcanon" ]
then
  echo "jhead: Original dimension for jhead: $1: $dim"
  jhead -autorot "$1"
else
 if [ "$gw0" == "$gw1" ] && [ "$gh0" == "$gh1" ]
 then
  echo "jhead: Good dimension for jhead: $1: $gw0"x"$gh0"
  jhead -autorot "$1"
 else
  if [ "$2" == "lossy" ]
  then
   echo "convert: Bad dimension for jhead: $1: $dim"
   while [ "$ans" != "yes" ] && [ "$ans" != "n" ] && [ "$ans" != "no" ]
   do
    echo -n "make a lossy rotation the image? (yes/no) "
    read ans
    if [ "$ans" == "yes" ]
    then
     echo Converted: original saved, rotated copy named "$name"_r.jpg
     convert -auto-orient "$1" "$name"_r.jpg
    fi
   done
  else
   echo "Bad dimension for jhead: $1: $dim"
  fi
 fi
fi
```